# Pinging a Celery Worker

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery worker that works off a queue brokered by RabbitMQ. When tasks are sent to this queue, all kind of crazy processing happens. I want to send a message to the worker and get an acknowledgement back letting me know that it's alive without the worker doing any processing (i.e., not doing the work that queue is dedicated to). Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect whether Celery is Available/Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506914/detect-whether-celery-is-available-running)

Answer (score 1):

Celery already include tons of functionality dedicated to monitoring, just have a look here

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html

If this page does not help you than you should really explain what you want to achieve and why.

Hope this helps