# How to get the status of celery broker and backend?

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

Is there a clean way in celery for knowing whether its broker and/or the result backend are down or not?

I am using celery with RabbitMQ broker and Redis backend.

Currently, the easiest way I found is submitting a dummy task which would raise `kombu.exceptions.OperationalError` when the broker is down, and `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError` when the backend is down.

This feels hacky, however. Is there a better way?

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001084/5832540)? Maybe a bit better than submitting task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the source files of Celery I ended up using the following

```
import celery
import kombu
import redis

try:
    with celery.current_app.connection_for_write() as conn:
        conn.connect()
        conn.release()
        print("Broker is working")
except(ConnectionError, kombu.exceptions.OperationalError):
    print("Broker is down")

try:
    celery.current_app.backend.get('Whatever')
    print("Backend is working")
except(ConnectionError, redis.exceptions.ConnectionError):
    print("Backend is down")
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not handle check rabbitmq connection